# markitUp WYSIWYG JQuery Editor, basic question - Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, markitup

I recently installed MarkItUp, the JQuery WYSIWYG editor located here: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/documentation/

It was a pretty easy install, and my text area looks correct. However, the text is submitted, and appears exactly how it looked in the text box. I.e. if bold in the text box is ** bold ** then thats what shows up in the view, ** bold **.

I feel like I've missed something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: edit your question add some of your code.

Comment: Hey David, I'm not really sure what code to be adding? I've included the scripts, and added the class to my textbox as instructed. My textbox does look like the WYSIWYG. Its just the text afterwards (in the show view in rails) doesn't get formatted any differently. Should I be doing something there?

Comment: Redcloth is an alternative for Textile!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some markdown parser ... I suggest Rdiscount .
[link text](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount)

have a good day!